# (dubble OAuth 2.0) After accessing OAuth 2.0 I see in JSON format again link with OAuth 2.0

Tags: javascript, json, xml, oauth-2.0, postman

After I accessing a live database with OAUTH2 on Postman, I get more then 2000 product titles with less description of each product in JSON FORMAT. To get more product information you will see a Link in each product titles in the less description. If I access in that link (get more product information) I have accessing again with OAUth2 in a new tab. (see below)

How can I access once to see all description of each products? Iv tried with Pre-request Scripts but does not work.

```
"items": [
    {
        "productId": "04a8137c-0de9-42d4-8959-f15ca2567862",
        "identifier": "12iB6",
        "name": "12 is Better Than 6",
        "platform": "Steam",

        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "description",
                "href": "https://api.codeswholesale.com/v1/products/04a8137c-0de9-42d4-8959-f15ca2567862/description"
```

Comment: How did you set this up in the Pre-request? Could you show an image of that? Why didn’t it work? Was there an error?

Answer (score 0):

I used this at Pre-request script

var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("{token}", data.token);

Error: There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  ReferenceError: responseBody is not defined